# Redirect from outside Angular to Angular route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect

I have a need to redirect from a page not using Angular to a page that does use Angular. It seems like it should work, but upon redirection Angular does not load, the route doesn't get processed and I just get essentially a blank page.

I am just calling:

```
window.location.href = '/#/myroute';
```

The URL bar appears as `https://myapp/#/myroute` which is what I'm expecting. When I refresh it works exactly as it's supposed to, but the automatic redirection is not working.

I tried adding `window.location.reload();` to my script after the location change, but it just caused an infinite loop.

Comment: while making `window.location.href = '/#/myroute';` does angular script files are loaded on the page? and angular has initialized on the page using either `ng-app`/`angular.bootstrap`..?

Comment: @charlietfl I think route has setup already..thats why it is working on page refresh

Comment: anything to do with `https` vs `http` maybe and blocked content?

Comment: I am confused: '/#/myroute' does not lead to another page, it leads to same page. (you can say - another part of same page)

Comment: Angular is not loaded on the page, and I want to redirect to another page that does use Angular. Petr you have nailed my problem but I don't understand how I can do the redirect. I tried changing the link to "https://myapp/#/myroute" but still had the same problem, I guess because the browser knows this is the same page.